# How to json decode in zoho

Tags: zoho

My json code : Input

```
{"responseCode":"200","responseText":"ID: 2ce934c860f48b02fb755178f8ac0a2"}
```

How to json decode in zoho creator
==> This is right ?

```
responseCode=jsondata.getJSON("responseCode");
responseText=jsondata.getJSON("responseText");
SMS_ID=responseText.getJSON("ID");
```

Comment: Please give me answer this is not php
This is zoho creator

Comment: You have tagged your question with PHP so you got your json in PHP?!

Comment: tagged php with zoho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's almost correct. Note that `"ID: 2ce934c860f48b02fb755178f8ac0a2"` is just a string, not a JSON element.

Try with:

```
responseText=jsondata.getJSON("responseText");
SMS_ID = responseText.remove("ID: ");
```

Comment: Please help me 
I find status from this code
{"responseCode":"200","responseText":"ID: 72e107588bc1e553427c8c72c6a4695a Status: 009"}

Comment: try with: SMS_ID = responseText.substring(45);

Comment: How to fetch url from below code

{"projects":[{"is_strict":"no","role":"admin","owner_name":"James Lozos","IS_BUG_ENABLED":true,"created_date_long":1502180785112,"owner_id":"647743525","link":{"task":{"url":"https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portal/sqmscrm/projects/1115954000000093005/tasks/"}}]}